# Ошибка TypeError: refresh_data() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, kivy, type-error

У меня есть класс для динамического отображения графиков, написанный с использованием kivy:

```
class Graph(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, root, name, x, y, height, width, time, graph_update_freq, data_update_freq, data_queue):
        self.root = root
        self.name = name
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.time = time
        self.graph_update_freq = graph_update_freq
        self.data_update_freq = data_update_freq
        self.data_queue = data_queue
        self.exist = True
        self.step = int((self.width - 40) * data_update_freq / self.time)
        self.len_graph_buf = int(self.time / data_update_freq)
        self.deviation = int(((self.width - 40) - ((self.len_graph_buf - 1) * self.step)) / 2)
        self.current_value = 0
        self.previous_value = 0
        self.graph_queue = []
        
        for i in range(0, self.len_graph_buf):
            self.graph_queue.append(0)


    def start_read_data(self):
        self.do_asyncio()

    def do_asyncio(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.refresh_data, 0.005)

    def refresh_data(self):
        if self.exist:
            self.canvas.clear()
            Builder.load_string('''
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 1, .1, .1, .9
                    Line:
                        points: 20 + self.deviation, 20, self.width - 20 - self.deviation, 20
                        width: 0.5
                    Color:
                        rgba: 69, 40, 66, 0.12
                    Line:
                        points: 20 + self.deviation, self.height - 20, self.width - 20 - self.deviation, self.height - 20
                        width: 0.5
                    Color:
                        rgba: 69, 40, 66, 0.12
                    Line:
                        points: 20 + self.deviation, self.height / 2, self.width - 20 - self.deviation, self.height / 2
                        width: 0.5   
                    Line:
                        points: 20 + self.deviation, self.height - (self.height / 2 + 20) / 2,
                                    self.width - 20 - self.deviation, self.height - (self.height / 2 + 20) / 2
                        width: 0.5
                    Color:
                        rgba: 69, 40, 66, 0.12
                    Line:
                        points: 20 + self.deviation, 10, 20 + self.deviation, self.height - 10
                        width: 0.5
                    Line:
                        points: self.width - 20 - self.deviation, 10,
                                    self.width - 20 - self.deviation, self.height - 10
                        width: 0.5
                    Line:
                        points: 20 + self.deviation, self.height / 2,
                                    self.width - 20 - self.deviation, self.height / 2
                        width: 0.5
                    ''')

            # TODO: масштаб
            while not len(self.data_queue) == 0:
                self.graph_queue.append(self.data_queue.pop(0) * int(self.height / 2 - 10))
                self.graph_queue.pop(0)

            j = len(self.graph_queue) - 1
            self.current_value = self.graph_queue[j]
            i = 0

            maxx = 1e-7
            for g in self.graph_queue:
                if abs(g) > maxx:
                    maxx = abs(g)
            
            mScale = (int(self.height / 2) - 20) / maxx

            for j in range(self.len_graph_buf - 2, -1, -1):
                self.previous_value = self.current_value
                self.current_value = self.graph_queue[j]
                self.l = Line(points=(i + 20 + self.deviation, int(-self.previous_value * self.mScale) + int(self.height / 2),
                                      i + self.step + 20 + self.deviation, int(-self.current_value * self.mScale) + int(self.height / 2)),
                                      fill='red')  # ???
                self.canvas.add(self.l)
                i += self.step

            Clock.schedule_once(self.refresh_data, self.graph_update_freq)

    def remove(self):
        self.exist = False
        self.root.destroy()
```

при запуске файла main, который ссылается на вышенаписанный класс возникает ошибка:  `TypeError: refresh_data() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. Насколько я знаю, такая ошибка обычно появляется, когда в аргументах функции класса забывают указать `self`, но у функции `refresh_data()` он есть, в качестве единственного аргумента. Подозреваю, что проблема в данной строке: `Clock.schedule_once(self.refresh_data, 0.005)` так как в документации kivy.clock нет ни одного примера, где бы первый аргумент (выполняемая функция) указывалась после `self.` но если убрать self, среда тут же просит его вернуть из-за явной ошибки. Заранее спасибо за помощь

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В документации вижу, что Clock.schedule_once принимает функцию с одним аргументом `dt`.

Ваша `refresh_data` никакого аргумента `dt` не ожидает, поэтому и ошибка. Решается вполне очевидным способом с помощью лямбды. Этот способ рекомендует и документация:

> Conversely, if you want to schedule a function that doesn’t accept the dt argument, you can use a lambda expression to write a short function that does accept dt

То есть вам нужно заменить строчку

```
Clock.schedule_once(self.refresh_data, self.graph_update_freq)
```

на такое:

```
Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.refresh_data(), self.graph_update_freq)
```

PS: Кстати, вот в этом утверждении:

> TypeError: refresh_data() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given. Насколько я знаю, такая ошибка обычно появляется, когда в аргументах функции класса забывают указать self

вы немножко не правы. Если вы методе забудете `self`, то получите ошибку `takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given` - то есть в описании функции 0 аргументов, но реально был передан неожиданный 1 аргумент self.

У вас же `takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` - то есть 1 аргумент (self) есть в описании функции, но в реальности в функцию было передано два аргумента (один - self, и один - dt, который в вашу функцию попытался передать Clock).

Comment: Спасибо. Проглядела этот момент в документации. Теперь правда другая ошибка, не связанная с предыдущей..  `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add'`. Не знаете, почему canvas воспринимается как Nonetype?

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы используете какой-то фреймворк, как в вашем случае Кivy, хорошо следовать его рекомендациям. И так

1. Вместо

   ```
   def refresh_data(self):
   ```

   примените

   ```
   def refresh_data(self, dt):
   ```

   `dt` - это параметр, который заполняется функцией `schedule_once()` (реальное время между планированием и спуском).

   **Вы можете затем использовать это значение или нет,** *но без этого параметра вы усложняете себе жизнь, не соблюдая намерения фреймворка.*

2. Вы вызываете функцию `schedule_once()` дважды в вашем коде, пытая запланировать запуск того же метода — `refresh_data()`.

   Это бы было в порядке, когда бы вы не планировали запуск этого метода *из него самого,* т.е. из метода `refresh_data()` (бесконечный цикл). Я не знаю, что вы хотели этим достичь, но удалите этот вызов.

Comment: Изначально вместо `Clock.schedule_once(self.refresh_data, self.graph_update_freq)` была функция из tkinter `self.root.after(self.graph_update_freq, self.refresh_data)`. Моя цель - перенести код  для отрисовки графиков в реальном времени с tkinter на kivy, чтобы приложение работало для мобильных устройств